# PostgreSQL permissions issue after upgrading to OS X Lion

Tags: macos, postgresql, osx-lion

After upgrading to Lion, I get the following error when trying to start up the Postgres server:

> pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid": Permission denied

I also tried to re-run the initdb command, but ran into a similar problem:

> initdb: could not access directory "/usr/local/var/postgres": Permission denied

If it matters, PostgreSQL was installed via Homebrew. Running `brew info postgresql` yields the expected results (version, summarized docs).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770649/repairing-postgresql-after-upgrading-to-osx-10-7-lion

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6814127/lion-update-removed-the-postgres-user-how-to-restore-it

Comment: Matt - Yeah, I saw that question, but I don't believe it's a path issue. Running `which psql` yields `/usr/local/bin/psql`, which should be the correct Homebrew path. I already have the proper path export set in .bash_login. Also, my issue is with starting the server, not connecting.

Comment: Those questions don't deal with a "path issue". They deal with a permission issue, because the postgres user got removed

Comment: The first question deals (mostly) with paths, the second with the postgres user being removed. Homebrew seemed to be hosed as well, so I'm going to uninstall/re-install and see if that works.

Answer (score 8):

Well, it turns out the solution was pretty simple. I changed the group on /usr/local/var to staff (from wheel) and changed the ownership (`chown -R`) to my system account (from root).

After that, postgres started up fine.

I was a little nervous changing those permissions, but the only thing in my /usr/local/var was a postgres directory, so all should be well. If you have other directories/files in /usr/local/var, maybe don't use the `-R` flag when chown'ing?

The Homebrew ruby installer script changes the group of /usr/local/var to staff, so that must have gotten undone when upgrading to Lion. Not sure about the ownership being root instead of my system account though...

Comment: just do be sure: you did `chgrp -R staff /usr/local/var` and `chown -R [username here] /usr/local/var`, right?

Answer (score 0):

sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/var

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, after I've checked I noticed that brew installed postgres on a different path and it is called postgresql@14 (version can be changed).

(used brew & M1 chip)

this made the trick:

```
pg_ctl -D /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14 start
```