# how to install postgresql for mac os x

Tags: macos, postgresql

I use homebrew,write this order to terminal.app to install postgresql.

```
`brew install postgresql`
<pre>==> Installing postgresql dependency: ossp-uuid  
==> Downloading ftp://ftp.ossp.org/pkg/lib/uuid/uuid-1.6.2.tar.gz  

curl: (7) couldn't connect to host  
Trying a mirror...  
==> Downloading http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.ossp.org/pkg/lib/uuid/uuid-1.6.2.tar.gz  
######################################################################## 100.0%  
==> ./configure --disable-debug --without-perl --without-php --without-pgsql --prefix=/usr/local/Cell  
==> make  
==> make install  
/usr/local/Cellar/ossp-uuid/1.6.2: 12 files, 332K, built in 62 seconds  
==> Installing postgresql  
==> Downloading http://ftp9.us.postgresql.org/pub/mirrors/postgresql/source/v9.1.1/postgresql-9.1.1.t  
######################################################################## 100.0%  
==> ./configure --disable-debug --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.1 --enable-thread-safety --  
==> make install-world  
==> Caveats  
# Build Notes  

If builds of PostgreSQL 9 are failing and you have version 8.x installed,  
you may need to remove the previous version first. See:  
  https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/issue/2510  

To build plpython against a specific Python, set PYTHON prior to brewing:  
  PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python  brew install postgresql  
See:  
  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/install-procedure.html  

# Create/Upgrade a Database  

If this is your first install, create a database with:  
  initdb /usr/local/var/postgres  

To migrate existing data from a previous major version (pre-9.1) of PostgreSQL, see:  
  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/upgrading.html  

# Start/Stop PostgreSQL  

If this is your first install, automatically load on login with:  
  mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents  
  cp /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.1/org.postgresql.postgres.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/  
  launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.postgresql.postgres.plist  

If this is an upgrade and you already have the org.postgresql.postgres.plist loaded:  
  launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.postgresql.postgres.plist  
  cp /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.1/org.postgresql.postgres.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/  
  launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.postgresql.postgres.plist  

Or start manually with:  
  pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start  

And stop with:  
  pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast  

# Other  

Some machines may require provisioning of shared memory:  
  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/kernel-resources.html#SYSVIPC  

If you want to install the postgres gem, including ARCHFLAGS is recommended:  
    env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg  

To install gems without sudo, see the Homebrew wiki.  
==> Summary  
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.1: 2739 files, 37M, built in 7.1 minutes  </pre>
```

This is my first install.
So, I write below.
    '$ initdb/usr/local/var/postgres'

but it's error. why??

```
-bash: initdb/usr/local/var/postgres: No such file or directory
```

next, I write below. It's also error.

```
`$ pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start`
<pre>sh: /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log: No such file or directory</pre>
```

I check it does finish to download.

```
`$ brew list`
<pre>
brew-gem    node        postgresql  readline
libyaml     ossp-uuid   rails       ruby
</pre>
```

I could see there is postgresql.

So, I don't know how I install postgresql.
I'm a very begginer.

Comment: `initdb/usr/local/var/postgres` looks like you need a space between `initdb` and `/usr...`.  However, this all seems rather off-topic.

Comment: Your problem was solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834118/posgresql-permissions-issue-after-upgrading-to-os-x-lion

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add a space after initdb:

```
$ initdb /usr/local/var/postgres
```